# Accelerometer calibration XNA

Tags: c#, windows, xna

I was working on a small game that utilizes data from the accelerometer. But my problem is that I wanted to give the player a chance to calibrate the game at any angle, not just flat. I have no idea how to do this. Any examples or explanations will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you're storing the data you get from the accelerometer event handler into an accessible variable (let's call it `accMeter`).

Basically, what you want to do is add the accelerometer data for several frames into a `Queue<Vector3>`.  To do this, call a method every frame (in your main update or wherever you are trying to calibrate) that will add your current accelerometer data into the queue, and once your queue is full, take the average of the `Vector3`s and store it into another variable (`defaultAcc`).  Then, whenever you're trying to figure out what the calibrated data is, just subtract `defaultAcc` from `accMeter`.